# How to copy data from Windows phone app internal storage to SD card or phone

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I need a way to copy a `.sdf` SQL Server CE database file from my Windows phone 8.1 app to a folder in either phone or SD.

My connection string

```
 data source=isostore:test.sdf
```

An example using any file is good also.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx

Comment: There is nothing I haven't tried

Comment: I'm having problems even accesing the file in the first place b4 thinking of copying to an sd card. I have a function to do,the wrting but not the reading

Comment: Look at the code generated by my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html

Comment: Nice write-up. Thanks for the effort @ErikEJ. I will focus on that for now. I needed to enable backup feature for the app. I will just leave that for now and focus on core features first. I WONDER IF ITS NECESSARY TO ALWAYS USE DATACONTEXT WITH LINQ TO SQL. I hope to use raw sql- I read it's not possible!!! I'm better with raw sql

Comment: On Phome, you must use LINQ to SQL

Comment: Ok thanks. U think its possible to copy out the data file to SD card on windows phone 8.1?